# how to relate current attribute value to the tag content

Tags: xml, xsd

I am solving problem in my XML doc. 
My doc example:
`<Height unit="m">lala</Height>`
 attribute `unit` has two values: `unit="m"` and `unit="ft"`. And I am suggesting is it possible to create XSD which will restric data type of child(text) of `Height` content.
For a example, then the `"m"` is set, height must be in float type, then the `"ft"` is set, height must be in string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible in XSD 1.0.  However, it may be possible in XSD 1.1 using a new feature called "conditional type assignment".